# Why did Eurus give the note from Culverton to Sherlock?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

What is Eurus' motive for giving the note from Culverton to Sherlock in season 4? Does she want Sherlock to catch Culverton or to make Sherlock creating trouble for himself?

Comment: More importantly, why is Culverton giving **Faith's ORIGINAL note** to Eurus in the first place...

Answer (score 7):

Two reasons I can think of:

1. Culverton asked her to, because he wanted Sherlock to make him more famous, with his accusation of being a serial killer:

> Culverton gave me Faith’s original note. (She stands up.) A mutual friend put us in touch.

There would be no reason for Culverton to give Faith's note to anyone, *unless* he wanted to play with Sherlock.

2. Eurus (in the guise of Faith) wanted to test Sherlock. From the same speech by Eurus

> I added some deductions for Sherlock. He was... quite good. But... he didn't get the *big* one.

Not only does she want to test Sherlock's deductions, she wants him to see the "big one":

[image]

Comment: +1 the point is to manipulate Sherlock - either Culverton wants to play him, Eurus wants to play him, or both!